# Extract Phone number only when other numbers are present in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I improve this regex to extract only numbers that contain "-" or no characters present between numbers inside string. For Example:

My phone number is 647-871-9067. tax year 2013. $9,846.22.

Should Extract `[647-871-9067]`

or

My phone number is 6478719067. tax year 2013. $9,846.22.

Should Extract `[6478719067]` only.

This is the regex I have written but it is extracting `2013` along with phone number

```
\b\s\(?([0-9-*)?]*)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: @Andrey please read my whole question again. My problem is different than what you have mentioned.

Comment: This is exactly the same problem -- regex for a phone number. At first it seems simple, e.g. create a general regex + some additional corner cases. When one needs to recognize more and more different formats, it's better to use a well tested library, e.g. one from [Google](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber). To get the idea, check this regex for punctuation within the number: `-x\u2010-\u2015\u2212\u30FC\uFF0D-\uFF0F \u00A0\u00AD\u200B\u2060\u3000()\uFF08\uFF09\uFF3B\uFF3D.\\[\\]/~\u2053\u223C\uFF5E`.

Comment: I m already using libphonenumber library. My question is about extracting phone number from a string that also contains other numbers, figures in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Below code regular expression will fetch only the phone number irrespective of '-' in between the phone number.

```
var string1 = '647-871-9067. tax year 2013. $9,846.22',
string2 = '6478719067. tax year 2013. $9,846.22',
regx = /(\d{3}-?\d{3}-?\d{4})/g;

string1.match(regx)   // will return "647-871-9067"
string2.match(regx)   // will return "6478719067"
```

Comment: I cannot use limits. I have users who are from different countries and every individual insert phone number in a different way.

Comment: @ashhad Well perhaps in some countries `2013` **is** a valid phone number. What is the rule you want to enforce for what is a phone number?